# Angular 6 - progress and slider bar

Tags: angular, angular6

[image: Sample Image]

I am looking for creating a widget as shown in the image. Can anybody help me on this?. I am using angular 6 for development.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Material progress bar component will give you a good starting point

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview#determinate